# how to get the selected items in DualListField?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

i don't have any idea on how to get the selected items in a DualListField. Can somebody help me. so here's my code on DualListField. And I want txtCat to be the container of the selected items aside from the TextCell. And also I want the selected item to be converted on its IDCategory

```
final DualListField<Category, String> field = new DualListField<Category, String>(category, toCategory, catProp.strName(), txCell);
        field.addValidator(new EmptyValidator<List<Category>>());
        field.setEnableDnd(true);
        field.setMode(Mode.INSERT);
        vlc.add(new FieldLabel(field, "Categories"), new VerticalLayoutData(1, -1, new Margins(10)));

        txtCat = new TextField();
        txtCat.setEmptyText("Value");
        txtCat.addFocusHandler(new FocusEvent.FocusHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {
                field.getFromStore();
            }
        });
        vlc.add(new FieldLabel(txtCat, "Chosen Categories"), new VerticalLayoutData(-18, -1, new Margins(10)));
```

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: There's [no DualListField in GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/allclasses-noframe.html). The community doesn't know how your custom class works.

Comment: Exactly... no duallistfield in GWT

Comment: if there is no duallistfield in GWT so how does duallistfield work in GXT?

Answer (score 0):

In latest GXT3 version [DualListField](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:duallistfield), You could get the selected items in ToView part through [field.getValue()](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/form/DualListField.html#getValue()) method. You get all the data in ToView as follows.   [field.getToView()](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/form/DualListField.html#getToView()).getStore().getAll() . hth

Comment: thanks @Wall-E
do you have any idea on how to add an editor in DualListField?

Comment: @alynallamedo  What is the editor class?  Can you please update the question with enough information? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: this is the declaration of the columnConfig of my category
ColumnConfig<UserRights, String> catConfig = new ColumnConfig<UserRights, String>(properties.categories(), 150);
                catConfig.setHeader("Categories");
                cfgs.add(catConfig);

and I want that to be edited whenever the catConfig is clicked.
so i would like to know on how could i add an editor(GridRowEditor) for a DualListField